# Clicking search bar doesn't open keypad (iOS Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uisearchbar

I'm an iOS noob, so sorry about that.

I made [a sample Search app (full code here)](https://github.com/tim-peterson/thinkful-PhotoSearchExample) that has the issue of when I click the search bar, it doesn't open the keypad

Can anyone help?

Here's my viewController.swift file:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  PhotoSearchExample
//
//  Created by Tim Peterson on 10/30/14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Tim Peterson. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

    let instagramClientID = "xxxxxx"

    func searchInstagramByHashtag(searchString: String) {
        for subview in self.scrollView.subviews {
            subview.removeFromSuperview()
        }

        let instagramURLString = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/" + searchString + "/media/recent?client_id=" + instagramClientID

        let manager = AFHTTPRequestOperationManager()

       self.scrollView.alpha = 0.0

        let activityIndictorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(activityIndicatorStyle: UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.Gray)
        activityIndictorView.center = self.view.center
        self.view.addSubview(activityIndictorView)
        activityIndictorView.startAnimating()

        manager.GET( instagramURLString,
            parameters: nil,
            success: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,responseObject: AnyObject!) in
                println("JSON: " + responseObject.description)

                if let dataArray = responseObject.valueForKey("data") as? [AnyObject] {
                    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320, CGFloat(320*dataArray.count))
                    for var i = 0; i < dataArray.count; i++ {
                        let dataObject: AnyObject = dataArray[i]
                        if let imageURLString = dataObject.valueForKeyPath("images.standard_resolution.url") as? String {
                            println("image " + String(i) + " URL is " + imageURLString)



                            let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRectMake(0, CGFloat(320*i), 320, 320))
                            self.scrollView.addSubview(imageView)
                            imageView.setImageWithURL( NSURL(string: imageURLString))

                            activityIndictorView.stopAnimating()

                            UIView.animateWithDuration(1.0, animations: {
                                self.scrollView.alpha = 1.0
                                }, completion: {
                                    (value: Bool) in
                                    println("Animation complete!")
                            })

                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            failure: { (operation: AFHTTPRequestOperation!,error: NSError!) in
                println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription)
        })
    }

    func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar!) {

        //println("search bar clicked!")

        searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
        searchInstagramByHashtag(searchBar.text)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

        searchInstagramByHashtag("clararockmore")
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be setting with iOS simulator. 
Goto iOS simulator -> hardware -> keyboard -> unselect "Connect Hardware Keyboard" or select "Toggle Software Keyboard".